# Oracle Get last know value if a column is NULL

Tags: oracle

Using Oracle I need to get the previous value just to fill a column .

I have `sealing_id` column and `assay_id` column.

I try :

```
LAG(sealing_id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY service_id DESC) AS sealing_id
```

but the query is too slow.

How can I just get the last know value to the sealing column if I have a NULL value ?

Comment: also try `SELECT sealing_id INTO sealing_id` but says innapropriate INTO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LAST_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions073.htm) analytic function. The IGNORE NULLS will keep the value in following NULL columns, but not in the first NULL column - see example.

```
create table x as 
select 0 x, NULL y from dual union all
select 1 x, 1 y from dual union all
select 2 x, NULL y from dual union all
select 3 x, 3 y from dual union all
select 4 x, NULL y from dual union all
select 5 x, NULL y from dual union all
select 6 x, 2 y from dual union all
select 7 x, NULL y from dual;

select x, y,
last_value(y ignore nulls) over (order by x) last_y 
from x order by x;
```

gives

```
        X          Y     LAST_Y
---------- ---------- ----------
         0                       
         1          1          1 
         2                     1 
         3          3          3 
         4                     3 
         5                     3 
         6          2          2 
         7                     2
```

And you are right, this query need sorting, it will return result a bit slower. But this sould be nearly comparable this a SELECT with ORDER BY on your ordering column.

Comment: Yes! it work´s thank you, it fill the NULL position, i am afraid i do not know how to specify the correct Order By criteria because, the values i get was not the last ones before i have a NULL value.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i81407) the syntax of the *order_by_clause*. Note that in my sample query I use the same ORDER BY column in the analytic function and in the query, which gives a 'nice' result.

Comment: I am trying to fill where i have NULL values :
SEALING | ASSAY
___________________
 NULL      | 3334222
3333333 | NULL
NULL | 3337333
2222222 | NULL
2222222 |